# Create multiple scaffolds from same index.html using grunt

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I have an index.html file which lists several dependencies. I'm using yeoman's generator-angular as a scaffold. I'd like to create a few multiple distribution builds, each with an index.html which includes varying subsets of those dependencies, using a grunt task.

I'm using usemin, but it doesn't provide this functionality. Files are plenty and in flux, so manually ignoring files for each build isn't feasible.

This could by accomplished I'm sure in many ways, e.g. by delimiting certain blocks to be omitted in certain builds (though I need to namespace them, so a binary yes/no delimiter - e.g. debug - wouldn't cut it). For example, if that functionality were provided by something that could pay attention to ignore blocks, with builds dev, simple, and dist:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Clotho</title>

        <!-- build:css(css) styles/main.css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/other.css">
        <!-- ignore:dist -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/another.css">
        <!-- endignore -->
        <!-- endbuild -->

</head>
<body>

    <header>...</header>

    <div class="container" id="mainContent"> ... </div>

    <!-- ignore:dist,simple -->
    <div class="container" id="devOnlyContent"> ... </div>
    <!-- endignore -->

    <footer>...</footer>

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->

    <!-- [libraries to be used by all] -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- [scripts to be used by all] -->
    <!-- build:js scripts/shared-module.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/shared.js"></script>
    <!--endbuild-->

    <!-- ignore:dev -->
    <script src="productionOnlyScript.js"></script>
    <!-- endignore -->


    <!-- ignore:simple -->
    <!-- build:js scripts/advanced-module.js --> 
    <script src="scripts/_foundation/_kickoff.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/_foundation/setup.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/_foundation/clothoDirectives.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/_foundation/extensions.js"></script>
    <!--endbuild-->
    <!-- endignore-->

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can use [grunt-processhtml](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-processhtml) to conditionally include dependencies (listed in a separate *.html partial) depending on which grunt target is active.

Also, after some googling I found this: https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-preprocess/.
It should provide the same functionality without a need to use separate partials, which is better.

Comment: I wish grunt-processhtml didnt have to use the build comment blocks, since I'm already using usemin which works the same way, but grunt-preprocess will do the trick. Thought I had seen it somewhere but couldn't find it when I looked again.

Comment: just for anyone else - processhtml lets you specify your own keyword, so you can use it in conjunction with usemin